# How to sync svn and cvs?

Tags: svn, ubuntu, cvs

We are recently migrated from `CVS` to `SVN` and I have setup SVN WebDAV on ubuntu server converting existing cvs repo. The developers start using new version control system SVN soon. What would be the best practice to migrate from svn to cvs back if anything goes wrong?(something like committing changes also to cvs while using svn).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds like a good backup would be your easiest solution.

Comment: Tailor can automatically sync back commits, but you really have nothing to gain by going back to cvs.

Comment: Ok... how to use `cvs2svn` 2nd time to convert the cvs projects to existing svn(overwrite)?

Comment: I suppose you could add an svn post-commit hook to also commit to cvs, although it sounds pretty messy. Maybe the post-commit hook should merely record the patch and the commit message to a queue which you can execute if and when there is a need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no reliable solution that I know of to keep CVS synchronized with **any** other version control system.  (There are some that claim to do so, but they are all very fragile.)  cvs2svn does *not* have an incremental mode that allows you to migrate additional CVS commits that have been added since the last cvs2svn conversion.  Incremental conversion of a CVS repository is technically difficult, not least because CVS has non-atomic commits, doesn't record the dates when branches/tags were created, and allows retroactive changes to the history of a project.

Your best bet for migrating away from CVS is to do a test conversion, have your developers try it out (with the understanding that any test commits will not be retained), then choose a flag day and do a one-way migration using cvs2svn.  I can hardly imagine that you will want to go back to CVS, but if you do, you don't have much alternative but to restore a backup of the CVS repo from before the conversion.

Disclaimer: I am the cvs2svn maintainer.

Comment: Unless someone like you reveal the truth, some people like me couldn't know what to do. Yes, the same way as you recommend to have testing environment where the developers check and commit changes for trial, I have setup and developers have to spend some time verifying the svn repo with no real commits. And I'm thinking if SVN support incremental restore/overwrite.